# Does Grounded on Xbox One support Mouse and Keyboard?

Tags: xbox-one, grounded

I just saw this cool game that came out recently and thinking of buying it for Xbox One, but I would prefer playing it with keyboard and mouse and not with controller, but I don't know if it works with it. Does the game work with a mouse and keyboard on Xbox One?

Answer (score 1):

Keyboard support appears to be available for the game on Xbox, but mouse input does not appear to work.

This [forum post](https://forums.obsidian.net/topic/115572-mouse-keyboard/) on the Obsidian website claims that keyboards appear to work but that is it:

> Playing on Xbox One, having the same problem - the game doesn't appear to be detecting the mouse. I can't "sign in" in the beginning of the game by clicking mouse buttons, and I can't turn with in the mouse inside the gameworld.

There are a few other forum posts on the site as well that state the same.

Comment: @Kerk an [Xbox Support Page](https://support.xbox.com/help/hardware-network/accessories/mouse-keyboard) states only select games have mouse support enabled and that you should consult the game to see if it does support it - but I couldn't see anything stating so on the store page for the game.  You would think that because the game is also available on Windows that it would support a mouse, but the Xbox must have some limitation in that sense that must be supported on a per-game basis.